# Python Request to SSL enabled server genetates SSL Handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl which makes a request to a server , but now I am getting a SSL error like this:

```
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: 
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake 
failure> (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),))
```

Is there a way to fix this?
I'm using Python 2.7.3 and requests==2.13.0

Comment: There are many similar posts about handshake failure with Python and your post does not contain enough information to either close it as a clear duplicate or to answer it. But, note that you have a very old version of Python which has no support for SNI yet. And with this age of Python it probably also uses an old OpenSSL version with no supports for newer ciphers or TLS versions. All of these limits can result in handshake failure.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how do i upgrade my python :) I tried all the other question solutions and they didn't work for me.

Comment: How to upgrade Python depends on the OS you are using. And if none of the many posts helped you then please be more specific on what you've tried and how it failed.